# what does "expression result unused" mean?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings

I solved the problem by following the links that appear when you start a question
they told me how, but not why...
so my question is to understand compiler warning language

In Xcode
I wanted a button that triggers an AlertView to assume the result of what the user enters therein:

```
UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
circumference = [textfield.text floatValue];
NSString *myString = textfield.text;
[_myButton setTitle:(@"%@",myString) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Well, it works, plus a warning.
I should pose my question here so: 
the warning said "Expression Result Unused". How do they figure that? I was using the result of the expression - right there on the button.

for those concerned, this is the fix:

```
UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
circumference = [textfield.text floatValue];
[_myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textfield.text] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: The *expression* `(@"%@",myString)` evaluates to `myString` (via the "comma operator") and thus the result of the first expression (`@"%@"`) is discarded/unused.

Comment: Do you use the var "myString" ,"circumference" anywhere else? If not, just remove it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1618867/2864740 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/8620506/2864740

Comment: @user2864740 - thanks for the links, interesting reading.

Comment: after reading the links, ( a fair bit is still over my head ) it seems using the comma as an operator sets up a little parameterStack from which the last entry is dropped when read. Hmmm, i can think of a use for it already

Comment: Your "fix" is incorrect (well technically it's correct, it's just pointless). Don't use `stringWithFormat` unless you actually need to format something. In this case you can directly use `textfield.text`. Get rid of the `stringWithFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[_myButton setTitle:(@"%@",myString) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

makes little sense.  I would actually expect a syntax error, but due to the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator/1618867#1618867)

```
(@"%@",myString)
```

is actually like writing

```
({
    @"%@";
    myString;
})
```

so you wrote the equivalent of

```
[_myButton setTitle:({
    @"%@";
    myString;
}) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

(And in case anyone is wondering, yes, [this is valid syntax as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732070/objective-c-declare-vars-with#19732119).)

So ultimately `(@"%@",myString)` evaluates to `myString`, but the expression `@"%@"` results unused and you get a warning.

`setTitle:forState:` expects a `NSString` as first parameter and you happen to have already have a `NSString`, named `myString`.

Just do

```
[_myButton setTitle:myString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Certain syntax choices (of just about any language) always surprise me xD

Comment: Good Explanation, and your variant works too, i just tried it and that's what i'll use. I'm not seasoned enough to break free from the Log-to-Console mentality.

Comment: By the way, you should never ever do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aString]`. It's completely useless and you are just wasting memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the value for the `textfield` in the variable `myString` but you are not using it anywhere else. That's why you got that warning *"Expression Result Unused"*. Just remove that line.

```
UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
circumference = [textfield.text floatValue];
//NSString *myString = textfield.text;
[_myButton setTitle:textfield.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Actually that line was commented out when i collected it from Xcode, I  used it that way up to the point of asking the question. I grabbed the whole shebangus of some variations i tried meaning to arrange it after pasting. I forgot. In the time it took to edit the question here, you slipped your comment in.

Comment: And in any case it would be a different warning. It would say something about the variable being unused, as opposed to the expression.

Comment: @aremvee this answer is wrong in any case. As I said, an unused variable and an unused expression generate two different warnings. The issue was cause by that weird construct you inadvertently used to pass the string as a parameter.